# Obtener valor entre un rango de fechas CAKEPHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Me gustaria obtener todos los datos que este en un rango de fechas, he probado la siguiente forma pero me da un error.

```
$data = $this->PedidosVentas->find()
    ->select(['cliente_id', 'centro_id', 'tipo_articulo_id'])
    ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
        return $exp->between('fecha', '2020-01-01','2020-01-31');
    })
    ->all();
```

Y me da el siguiente error Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\PedidosVentasController::App\Controller{closure}() must be an instance of App\Controller\QueryExpression, instance of Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression given, called in C:\wamp64\www\proyecto\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Query.php on line 2246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione así.

```
$condiciones = array('fecha BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-31"'=> array('2020-01-01','2020-01-31'));

$data = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('fecha BETWEEN "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-31"')));
```